# jquery :nth-child() class is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is not working

```
$(".text_read:nth-child(2)").css("background", "transparent url('images/text_read2.png') no-repeat");
```

above code's result is same as below code

```
$(".text_read").css("background", "transparent url('images/text_read2.png') no-repeat");
```

And my HTML code is

```
<div class="welcome">
                    <p class="welcometext">MORE UPCOMING NEWS FOR INTERNATIONAL EVENTS</p>
                    <div class="all_international_img row-fluid">
                    <div class="welcome-image span4 international_img">
                        <img src="images/img1.png">
                        <div class="text_read">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a </div>
                    </div><!--all_international_img row-fluid-->
                    <div class="welcome-image span4 international_img">
                        <img src="images/img1.png">
                        <div class="text_read">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a </div>
                    </div><!--all_international_img row-fluid-->
                    <div class="welcome-image span4 international_img">
                        <img src="images/img1.png">
                        <div class="text_read">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a </div>
                    </div><!--all_international_img row-fluid-->
                    </div><!--all_international_img-->
                </div><!--welcome-->
```

Comment: seems fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kXLEn/1/

Comment: "Selects all elements that are the nth-child of their parent." From http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/.

Comment: What elements do you expect to receive the background?

Comment: There is no child element  of class txt_read.

Comment: What is the result you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
$(".text_read").eq(2).css({"background", "transparent url('images/text_read2.png') no-repeat"});
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you want to use [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) instead

```
$('.text_read:eq(2)')
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UbpkL/)

Answer (score 2):

Use instead `:nth` in `.eq()`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UbpkL/1/)

```
$('.text_read:nth(2)');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Eq to get the child element

```
$('.text_read).eq(0);
```